# CMFCRebar on a dialog box

Tags: mfc, pack

Can we create a CMFCRebar on a dialog box? If yes, then how? I need to have a CMFCReBar drawn on a dialog box with a toolbar and and menubar.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of examples of how to add a toolbar to a CDialog. Have you tried to take one of those samples and modify CDialog with the new CDialogEx and CRebar with CMFCReBar? I haven't tried it but maybe it works.

By the way, there is a tag specific for MFC feature pack questions (mfc-feature-pack). Maybe you should add this tag.

Regards,

Javier